# `solana airdrop 10 <pub-key>` Error: connection timed out

Tags: solana

I am running:

```sh
solana airdrop 10 7Fbdg5vecamm8MLxDw7bPN2xENaBE7fP65tKW935BEhq
```

Where `7Fbdg5vecamm8MLxDw7bPN2xENaBE7fP65tKW935BEhq` is my public key.

However, I'm getting the following output:

```sh
Requesting airdrop of 10 SOL from 109.230.214.107:9900
Error: connection timed out
```

My config is:

```
$ solana config get
Config File: /Users/patrick/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.devnet.solana.com 
WebSocket URL: wss://api.devnet.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /Users/patrick/.config/solana/id.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you did everything right, so it could be a few things:

- You were requesting too much SOL all at once.  Typically, you should airdrop 1 at a time.
- The network was bogged down at the time. This can happen, especially on devnet
- The Solana tool suite is out of date.  Be sure to update to the latest version, which is 1.7.10 at the time of writing, using `solana-install init 1.7.10`

One of those should do the trick!